# problem to give screenOptions to the DrawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I was facing trouble using `createDrawerNavigator`. I was following [there](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#screenoptions) Docs and try to implement something like this:

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const MenuNavigator = createStackNavigator();

const HeaderOptions = {
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#512DA8',
  },
  headerTintColor: '#fff',
  headerTitleStyle: {
    color: '#fff',
  },
};
function MenuNavigatorScreen() {
  return (
    <MenuNavigator.Navigator
      //initialRouteName
      screenOptions={HeaderOptions}
    >
      //Screens
    </MenuNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator();
function HomeNavigatorScreen() {
  return (
    <HomeNavigator.Navigator
      //initialRouteName
      screenOptions={HeaderOptions}
    >
      //Screen
    </HomeNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
const MainNavigator = createDrawerNavigator();
function MainNavigatorDrawer() {
  return (
    <MainNavigator.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Home"
      drawerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: '#D1C4E9',
      }}
      screenOptions={HeaderOptions} //Isn't it should be applied to all  screen
    >
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="Home" component={HomeNavigatorScreen} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="Menu" component={MenuNavigatorScreen} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="About" component={component1} />
      <MainNavigator.Screen name="Contact" component={component2} />
    </MainNavigator.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I got the header in the `Home` and `Menu` but in the `About` and `Contact` screen there is no header. I think `screenOptions` isn't working in the `DrawerNavigator`, then how to give them this options?

> [image: iamge1]

> [image: image2]

And one more thing, I realize that I repeat my code many times. Is there any better approach? 
I heartily thank if anyone helps me to figure out this.

---

Ok, I solve the header issue by turning my component1 and component2 into a stackNavigator like:

```js
const stack = createStackNavigator();
function AboutNavigatorScreen() {
  return (
    <stack.Navigator screenOptions={HeaderOptions}>
      <stack.Screen name="About" component={component1} />
    </stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function ContactNavigatorScreen() {
  return (
    <stack.Navigator screenOptions={HeaderOptions}>
      <stack.Screen name="Contact" component={component2} />
    </stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

What I understand is "If I need to add any `screenOptions` in my component the turn it into a stacknagivator" which seem odd. Am I right or over-engineering my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Good day, to implement the header on the site, you need to specify the  `screenOptions={{headerShown: true}}>` in Driver.Navigator.
And then prescribe options

```js
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import {Home} from '../screens/Home'

import LeftBurgerMenu from "../components/LeftBurgerMenu";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export const AppNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator
                initialRouteName="Home"
                              drawerContentOptions={{
                activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
                itemStyle: {marginVertical: 30}
            }}
                              screenOptions={{
                                  headerShown: true,
                              }}>
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={() => <Home/>}
                               options={{
                                   headerTintColor: '#fffffd',
                                   headerTitle: () => <Text>Title</Text>,
                                   headerLeft: () => <BackArrow/>,
                               }}
                />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```